# C# API for MS Word Equation editor

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, omml

Is there an API (preferably C#) to access the object model of equations created with MS Word's equation editor? I am looking for an API like the chart object to access properties of charts in Excel, for instance.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe there is one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called "Office MathML" (OMML) or sometimes "Ecma MathML". You can learn more about it [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/murrays/archive/2006/10/07/MathML-and-Ecma-Math-_2800_OMML_2900_-.aspx). You have access to it via the Open XML format. These days, most people are using the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en) to access Office's XML vocabulary. Use the [DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.math(office.14).aspx) namespace.